# video.js is fastSeek possible and if so how?

Tags: video.js

Can you do `fastSeek` in video.js? If so, how do you achieve it?

I've tried:

```
this.video.fastSeek(10)
```

but it says `fastSeek` is not a function and I can't find a reference to `fastSeek` in the docs. Does it use `fastSeek` under the hood if its available? If it is available, how do you control whether it uses `fastSeek` or not?

I've found this unit test in the docs but I'm not sure what it means not whether its available in the latest video.js release:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/8913f798dc6be127cbfba2e37e0f79e329c31257/test/unit/tech/html5.test.js#L54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not used in Video.js. You could call it on the video element with `player.tech(true).el().fastSeek(10)`

Comment: this look ok? ... if (this.video.tech(true).el().fastSeek) {
      this.video.tech(true).el().fastSeek(t)
    } else {
      this.video.currentTime(t)
    }

Comment: yes that should do it